# could to find or load main class org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob

Tags: hadoop, solr, nutch

I'm using Linux with Hadoop, Cloudera and HBase.

Could you tell me how to correct this error?

Error: `could to find or load main class org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob`

The following command gave me the error:

```
src/bin/nutch inject crawl/crawldb dmoz/
```

if you need any other information ask for me.

Answer (score 2):

I think you probably missed a step or two. Please confirm:

1. Did you install Apache ANT and then navigate to the nutch folder and type in "ant"?
2. Did you set the environment variables:

   - NUTCH_JAVA_HOME: The java implementation to use.  Overrides `JAVA_HOME`.
   - NUTCH_HEAPSIZE: The maximum amount of heap to use, in MB. Default is 1000.
   - NUTCH_OPTS: Extra Java runtime options.Multiple options must be separated by white space.
   - NUTCH_LOG_DIR: Log directory `(default: $NUTCH_HOME/logs)`
   - NUTCH_LOGFILE: Log file `(default: hadoop.log)`
   - NUTCH_CONF_DIR:  Path(s) to configuration files `(default: $NUTCH_HOME/conf)`. Multiple paths must be separated by a colon ':'.
   - JAVA_HOME
   - NUTCH_JAVA_HOME
   - NUTCH_HOME

If you install using "ant", then you will get a new folder in `/nutch called /nutch/runtime/local` and this is from where you must actually run nutch.

Tip: Try reading [this page](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial).